# Удаление колонок DF по списку

Tags: python, pandas, re, индексация

Есть таблица, состоящая более чем из 20 столбцов. Нужно удалить в ней определённые столбцы. А именно: сохранить в итоговой таблице столбцы 'Отдел', 'Имя' и ВСЕ столбцы "Факт", а все столбцы "План" удалить.

Можно их удалить, вписав все индексы `df.drop(df.columns[[2,4,6,...]], axis=1, inplace=True)`, но я хочу научиться делать это правильно, через цикл.

Таблица:

```
    rows = [
        ('A','Олег', '1',1,2,6),
        ('C','Маша', 1,1,2,6),
        ('V','Паша', '1',1,2,6),
        ('R','Игорь', '0',1,2,6)
    ]
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=['Отдел','Имя', 'Январь 2022. План.', 'Январь 2022.Факт', 'Февраль 2022.План.', 'Февраль 2022.Факт'])
```

Пробовал создать список и сравнивать столбцы со списком, но несколько столбцов имеют меняющееся названия "месяц" - 'Январь 2022. План.', 'Февраль 2022. План.' и так 12 раз, поэтому не получается.

Пробовал так:

```
    column = ['Отдел','Имя', 'Факт']
    
    for col in df.columns:
        if col not in column:
            df.drop(columns=[col], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Потом попробовал с re:

```
    import re
    
    for col in df.columns[2:]:
        if col != re.search('^\w+\s\d+.\w+\s\w+.', col):
            df.drop(columns=[col], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Тоже не получается...
Понимаю, что можно еще пройтись и по индексам, т.к. есть определенная цикличность, но не соображу как записать цикл.
БУДУ БЛАГОДАРЕН за 2 варианта цикла: 1 найти подстроку в строке и 2 удаление по индексам.
В итоге должно получиться:

```
      Отдел    Имя Январь 2022.Факт  Февраль 2022.Факт
    0     A   Олег                1                  1
    1     C   Маша                1                  1
    2     V   Паша                1                  1
    3     R  Игорь                0                  1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071199/drop-columns-whose-name-contains-a-specific-string-from-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains(r"\bПлан\b")]
```

или так если столбцы, которые нужно удалить, заканчиваются строго на одну и ту же подстроку: `План.`:

```
res = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.endswith("План.")]
```

---

результат:

```
In [499]: res
Out[499]:
  Отдел    Имя  Январь 2022.Факт  Февраль 2022.Факт
0     A   Олег                 1                  6
1     C   Маша                 1                  6
2     V   Паша                 1                  6
3     R  Игорь                 1                  6
```

---

> Как удалить столбцы по их индексам?

```
idx_to_drop = [2, 4]
res = df.drop(columns=df.columns[idx_to_drop])
```

Comment: спасибо!
Понял, что привел не удачный пример таблицы, в жизни нужно удалить несколько столбцов, а именно 3. Их можно добавить в эту конструкцию по ключевым словам? 
(r"\bПлан\b", r"\bКрасный\b", r"\bМороз\b") ?

Comment: @Александр, `r"\b(?:План|Красный|Мороз)\b"`

Comment: @Александр, [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow) ;)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: А по индексам не знаете как?

Comment: столбцы в цикле удалить по индексам?

Comment: @Александр, дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, но это не совсем то, у нас их (столбцов) много , больше 20. Предполагал, что по определенной логике будут идти итерации + счетчик в цикле.

Comment: @Александр, откройте новый вопрос с __воспроизводимым__ примером данных и с результатом, который вы хотите получить. PS я считаю, что я ответил на данный вопрос в его текущей формулировке и он работает для приведенного примера данных ;)

Answer (score 0):

> сохранить в итоговой таблице столбцы 'Отдел','Имя' и ВСЕ столбцы
> "Факт"

Можно ещё примерно так:

```
columns = [col for col in df.columns if col in {'Отдел','Имя'} or 'Факт' in col]
df = df[columns]
```

По вкусу добавить где нужно `.lower()`, `.endswith()` и т.д.